# Nested ifelse() or case_when() for unknown number of queries in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data frame which I would like to group according to the value in a given row and column of the data frame

```
my_data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 4))
colnames(my_data) <- c('Position', 'Group', 'Data')
                      
my_data[,1] <- c('A1','B1','C1','D1')
my_data[,3] <- c(1,2,3,4)

grps <- list(c('A1','B1'),
             
             c('C1','D1'))

grp.names = c("Control", "Exp1", "EMPTY")


my_data$Group <- case_when(
  my_data$Position %in% grps[[1]] ~ grp.names[1],
  my_data$Position %in% grps[[2]] ~ grp.names[2]
)
```

OR

```
my_data$Group <- with(my_data, ifelse(Position %in% grps[[1]], grp.names[1],
                                    ifelse(Position %in% grps[[2]], grp.names[2], 
                                    grp.names[3])))
```

These examples work and produce a Group column with appropriate labels, however I need to have flexibility in the length of the `grps` list from 1 to approximately 25.

I see no way to iterate through `case_with` or `ifelse` in a `for` loop eg.

```
my_data$Group <- for (i in 1:length(grps)){
  case_when(
    my_data$Well %in% grps[[i]] ~ grp.names[i])
}
```

This example simply deletes the Group column

What is the most appropriate way to handle a variable `grps` length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your question implies that the `grps` variable is a list and every element in that list is itself an array that holds all the positions that belong to that group.

Specifically, in your `grps` variable below, if the Position is "A1" or "B1" it belongs to the whatever your first entry is `grp.names`. Similarly, if the position is "C1" or "D1" it belongs to whatever your second entry is in `grp.names`

```
> grps
[[1]]
[1] "A1" "B1"

[[2]]
[1] "C1" "D1"
```

Assuming that to be the case you can do the following:

```
matching_group_df <- sapply(grps, function(x){ my_data$Position %in% x})
selected_group <- apply(matching_group_df, 1, function(x){which(x == TRUE)})
my_data$Group <- grp.names[selected_group]

  Position   Group Data
1       A1 Control    1
2       B1 Control    2
3       C1    Exp1    3
4       D1    Exp1    4
```

The way it works is as follows:

1. `matching_group_df` is a matrix of True/False (created via the `sapply` function) that specifies what group index the position belongs to:

```
> matching_group_df
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE
```

2. You then select the column that has the `TRUE` value row by row using an apply command:

```
selected_group <- apply(matching_group_df, 1, function(x){which(x == TRUE)})

> selected_group
[1] 1 1 2 2
```

3. Finally you pass those indices to your grp.names list to select the appropriate ones and set them into your original dataframe.

```
grp.names[selected_group]
[1] "Control" "Control" "Exp1"    "Exp1"
```

This also has the small side benefit of just using base R functions if that is important to you.

Comment: This has worked perfectly with the addition of this line `selected_group <- as.numeric(selected_group)` to handle NULL values

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach 1: Hash table

I would opt for a different approach here, as group makeup might change during analysis, specifically a lookup table of key-value pairs, and write a small accessor function.

```
library(tidyverse)

# First, a small adjustment to `grps` to reflect an empty group.
grps <- list(c('A1','B1'),
             c('C1','D1'),
             NULL)
names <- unlist(grps, use.names = F)
values <- rep(grp.names, map_dbl(grps, length))

h = as.list(values) %>%
  set_names(names) %>%
  list2env()

# find x in h
f <- Vectorize(function(x) h[[x]], c("x")) # scoping here
```

This takes some time to setup, but usage is quite convenient:

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(Groups = f(Position))

  Position   Group Data
1       A1 Control    1
2       B1 Control    2
3       C1    Exp1    3
4       D1    Exp1    4
```

This avoids having to change your code in multiple places, and can take on arbitrary length of groups.

#### Approach 2: Dynamic switch

Alternatively, we can make an arbitrary length `switch` expression, building it from the group names and their unique values.

```
constructor <- function(ids, names){
  purrr::imap_chr(as.character(ids), ~paste(paste0("\"", .x ,"\""),
                                            paste0("\"", names[.y], "\""),
                                            sep = "=")) %>%
    paste0(collapse = ", ") %>%
    paste0("Vectorize(function(x) switch(as.character(x), ", ., ", NA))", collapse = "") %>%
    str2expression()
}

my_data %>%
  mutate(Group = eval(constructor(names, values)))
```

In this case, it would evaluate the expression

```
expression(Vectorize(function(x) switch(as.character(x), A1 = "Control", 
    B1 = "Control", C1 = "Exp1", D1 = "Exp1", 
    NA)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item in my_data$Position you want to go through each of the grps and look for a match and assign grp.names, if so. If you don't find a match in any grp, assign grp.names[3]:

```
my_data$Group <- lapply(my_data$Position, function(position){ # Goes through each my_data$Position
  for(i in 1:length(grps)){
    if(position %in% grps[[i]]){
      return(grp.names[i]) # Give matching index of grp.names to grps
    } else if (i == length(grps)){ # if no matches assign grp.names[3]
      return(grp.names[3])
    }
  }
}) %>% unlist() # Put the list into a vector
```